# How to simplify my code - extract all node values of same xml tag name

Tags: python, xml, minidom

For example, here is the XML data:

```
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
     <reportList>
        <reportName>report 1</reportName>
     </reportList>
     <reportList>
        <reportName>report 2</reportName>
     </reportList>
     <reportList>
        <reportName>report 3</reportName>
     </reportList>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Here is my code to extract the node values of all **reportName**, and it works.

```
import xml.dom.minidom
...
node = xml.dom.minimom.parseString(xml_file.text).documentElement
reportLists = node.getElementsByTagName('reportList')

reports = []
for reportList in reportLists:
    reportObj = reportList.getElementsByTagName('reportName')[0]
    reports.append(reportObj)

for report in reports:
    nodes = report.childNodes
    for node in nodes:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            print (node.data)
```

result:

```
report 1
report 2
report 3
```

Although it works, I want to simplify the code. How to achieve the same result using shorter code?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify both `for` loops using list comprehensions:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
node = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_file.text).documentElement
reportLists = node.getElementsByTagName('reportList')

reports = [report.getElementsByTagName('reportName')[0] for report in reportLists]
node_data = [node.data for report in reports for node in report.childNodes if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE]
```

`node_data` is now a list containing the information you were printing.